# flutter textformfield: controller not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a `textFormField`. However, when I add controller to it, the keyboard does not type anything. When I remove it it starts to type. Any help?

In the InputDecoration field I tried `isDensed:true` but still not working.
Any help?

```
final TextEditingController phone = TextEditingController();


TextFormField(textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      phone.text = value;
                    },
                    controller: phone,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 50,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
```

Comment: you don't have to update controller onChanged: (value) {}. remove `phone.text = value;` and it will work as expected and you can still access the value anywhere else with `phone.text`

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I don't understand why in my previous app, the onChanged (valu){}  phone.text = value worked, but this isn't

Comment: Have to look into your code to explain this. But the controller have value when you write anything in field and don't have to add it again.